# why is PowerPivot Health Statistics Collector Timer Job trying to get data from an older powerpivot instance?

Tags: timer-jobs, powerpivot, health-analyzer

We are relocating one SSAS PowerPivot service instance from the local server to a remote one, but the timer job is still trying to connect to the service instance and we are getting empty values.

we have disabled the older PowerPivot service : servername\PowerPivot and the sql browser service on the server

we also removed the service from the excel services data model settings, but we are still facing this issue

Any idea why the timer job is trying to connect to the older PowerPivot instance, and how can we remove it ?